# Laravel $request->all() correctly returns data, but $_POST completely empty

Tags: laravel, post

I am making an ajax post request to the server, posting json data. In firebug I can see the network post call going through along with the json data.

In Laravel I was trying to do a simple var dump of the `$_POST` data and have just wasted a fair bit of time being confused as to why this should be completely empty. However, when I use the Request facade, my data is there.

ie. this just gives me an empty array:

```
public function test(){
    Log::info($_POST);
}
```

...yet this prints my data, as I expect:

```
public function test(Request $request){
    Log::info($request->all());
}
```

Why?

**Edit**

Thanks, @Webdesigner. The http verb is definitely `post`, as my method is called in my routes file via

`Route::post('/image-upload', 'EntryController@test'); // Note "post" verb`

I don't think `$request->post()` is valid in Laravel 5.4 as this throws an `BadMethodCallException: Method post does not exist.` error. However, I can confirm that

`Log::info($request->method()); // POST`

also tells me the method is post.

Very strange. I guess you're right that some part of the app is overwriting the $_POST global, though I have no idea why/where/how. Probably not relevant, but this call is being made from Angular 4.

Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: @developernator You have incorrectly assumed that it was me who downvoted you.

Comment: @Webdesigner I am using Laravel 5.4

Comment: Can you check the exact data (HTTP Header, URL, POST, Data, Cookies, etc.) that is communicated to the server in you Browser Network analytics?

Answer (score -1):

This is not the normal behavior of Laravel. I tested this on a fresh Laravel 5.5 site and just did a Form submit and an Ajax POST request to the same Route.

Both give me the same result. A POST Request should have at least the CSRF Token as `_token` with a value.

One other point is `$request->all()` is not only the the content of `$_POST` so to have a fair compression you should try `$request->post()`.

BTW only because you did a POST request do not mean that the data is send by the POST Method, it could be that the data you see in `$request->all()` is from $_GET and $_COOKIE, etc and only the Method was a POST.

Last but not least there it the option that some part of your APP is deleting the content of the Superglobal Variables. `$_POST` and the others are not like constants, so they can be changed during  runtime e.g. `$_POST =  []`;

*I don't thing that there is a difference in Laravel 5.4.27.*

Comment: Thank you. Please see my edit to the question in response to you.